# Check if an UIImageView is on subview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, subview

In my app I need to call some `UIViews` more than once. But in one of my method, i've a code like :

```
[self addSubview:UIImageView];
```

But i've read that `addsubview` method must be call once. So, to let the code how is it, how could I check if it's already on subview ? Like :

```
if ([UIImageView isOnSubview] == NO)
{
    [self addSubview:UIImageView];
}
```

Because I don't find any method to check this :/

Thank you !

Comment: Why `addSubview` should be called only 1 time ? If it's what you said…

Comment: if ([UIImageView superView]){ //here you go }

Comment: Is `UIImageView` an instance of a `UIImageView` object or is it a `UIImageView` mean the `UIImageView` class? Your naming of your objects is very bad. Your should  name something that is already a class name.

Comment: @Lucien : addSubview method should be called only once, i've seen it a lot of time on other subjects.

Comment: @meccan : No, because you need to add the image view one time.

Comment: @Popeye : UIImageView is the name of an element, so it's an object, from UIImageView. With the explainations above, it's more easy to see you're agree.

Comment: @user2057209 if (![imageView superView]){ [self addSubview: imageView] }

Comment: I don't know what you mean by `addsubview method must be call once`. Then how do you do to add multiple labels, view, button… programatically ?

Comment: @meccan Correct too in this case !

Comment: @Lucien : There is a difference between call multiple addSubview for only one object (incorrect) and call multiple addSubview for differents objects (correct) !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are probably looking for UIView's `-(BOOL)isDescendantOfView:(UIView *)view;` taken in [UIView class reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html).

Comment: But how could i use it in this case ?

Comment: [imageView isDescendantOfView:self.view]

Comment: @Adithya i cant able to apply your filtering(answer) in my solution.If you don't mind can you elaborate the answer with one sample code  - Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

use this one

```
 for (UIView *subview in [self subviews])
 {
     NSLog(@"%@", subview);
     // ---------- remember one thing there should be one imageview ------
     if(![subview isKindOfClass:[UIImageView class]])
     {
           [self addSubview:UIImageView];
     }
 }
```